# How to get AVPlayer to redraw current AVItem videoComposition when paused

Tags: macos, avfoundation, avplayer, core-image

I'm building a simple video editor for macOS: A movie file is loaded as an AVAsset, transformed by a series of CIFilters in a AVVideoComposition, and played by an AVPlayer. I present UI controls for some of the parameters of the CIFilters.

When video is playing everything is working great, I slide sliders and effects change! But when the video is paused the AVPlayerView doesn't redraw after the controls in the UI are changed.

How can I encourage the AVPlayerView to redraw the contents of the videoComposition of it's current item when it's paused?

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @objc @IBAction func openDocument(_ file: Any) { ... }

    @IBOutlet weak var moviePlayerView: AVPlayerView!

    var ciContext:CIContext? = CIContext(mtlDevice: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)

    var sliderValue: Double = 0.0

    @IBAction func sliderMoved(_ sender: NSSlider) {
        self.sliderValue = sender.doubleValue
        // need to update the view here when paused
        self.moviePlayerView.setNeedsDisplay(self.moviePlayerView.bounds)
        // setNeedsDisplay has no effect.
    }

    func loadMovie(file: URL) {
        let avMovie = AVMovie(url: file)
        let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avMovie)

        avPlayerItem.videoComposition = AVVideoComposition(asset: avMovie) { request in
            let output = request.sourceImage.applyingGaussianBlur(sigma: self.sliderValue)
            request.finish(with: output, context: self.ciContext)
        }

        self.moviePlayerView.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out re-setting the AVPlayerItem's `videoComposition` property will trigger the item to redraw. This works even if you set the property to it's current value: `item.videoComposition = item.videoComposition`. The property setter appears to have undocumented side effects.

To fix the sample code above, do this:

```
@IBAction func sliderMoved(_ sender: NSSlider) {
    self.sliderValue = sender.doubleValue
    // update the view when paused
    if self.moviePlayerView.player?.rate == 0.0 {
        self.moviePlayerView.player?.currentItem?.videoComposition = self.moviePlayerView.player?.currentItem?.videoComposition
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone finds this useful!

Comment: The problem is AVPlayer starts playing the moment you set videoComposition property. How do you fix it?

Comment: Ok I think with this workaround, the player doesn't starts playing. If I set videoComposition to first nil and then the old value, then player starts playing.

Comment: I also noticed this behaviour has changed in Catalina Beta 5 (19A526h). I have filed a bug with Apple. For me, setting videoComposition to nil and then the old value does 'work' in Catalina but the performance is unacceptably bad and many errors are logged to the console.

Comment: macOS 10.15 and iOS 13 can be fixed by:
`player.currentItem?.videoComposition = player.currentItem?.videoComposition?.mutableCopy() as? AVVideoComposition`