# Force Redraw of AVPlayerLayer when it is paused on iOS 13

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, core-image, cifilter

I apply real time effects using CoreImage to video that is played using AVPlayer. The problem is when the player is paused, filters are not applied if you tweak filter parameters using slider.

```
  let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: {[weak self] request in

        // Clamp to avoid blurring transparent pixels at the image edges
        let source = request.sourceImage.clampedToExtent()
        let output:CIImage

        if let filteredOutput = self?.runFilters(source, filters: array)?.cropped(to: request.sourceImage.extent) {
             output = filteredOutput
         } else {
             output = source
         }


        // Provide the filter output to the composition
        request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
    })
```

As a workaround, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339414/how-to-get-avplayer-to-redraw-current-avitem-videocomposition-when-paused/52363038#comment101391259_52363038) answer that worked till iOS 12.4, but not anymore in iOS 13 beta 6. Looking for solutions that work on iOS 13.

Comment: Have you tried `player.seek(to: player.currentTime())`?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't work either.

Comment: Hmm, tricky… Have you tried un-setting and re-setting the `playerItem`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reporting this as a bug to Apple and getting some helpful feedback I have a fix:

```
player.currentItem?.videoComposition = player.currentItem?.videoComposition?.mutableCopy() as? AVVideoComposition
```

The explanation i got was:

> AVPlayer redraws a frame when AVPlayerItem’s videoComposition property gets a new instance or, even if it is the same instance, a property of the instance has been modified.

As a result; forcing a redraw can be achieved by making a 'new' instance simply by copying the existing instance.